# Why do I detect a facebook redirect when accessing random websites?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, facebook

[Windows 7 x64]

Today, after locking out facebook.com by modifying my hosts file I have ntocied that I cannot surf to seemingly random pages on the internet anymore, be they from google results or directly clicked link on other pages. In such a case I get a "Server not found" error.

I copied one of the links that lead to this problem:
(anonymised domain i was surfing substituting "somedomaindawg")

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=46468144668&domain=somedomaindawg&origin=1&redirect_uri=http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/BhKMRj1sUPu.js?version=41#cb=f6afd12dc&domain=somedomaindawg&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fsomedomaindawg%2Ff299bb353c&relation=parent&response_type=token,signed_request,code&sdk=joey
```

Now, I assume that they have some...facebook widget on their page which cannot be accessed.

Is this an example of "coder fail" in the sense that he/she/they did not provide for the case that fb might actually be unreachable and instead of keeping the page on "somedomaindawg" as is they redner it unsuable by forcing the fault to be rendered by the browser ?

Comment: The references to `facebook.com` (which appears twice) should be a clue ...

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure, as I'm not sure what website you're visiting or what is happening or what events occurred prior to that facebook URL being opened, but I presume that:

It might have something to do with a Facebook advertising scheme (like google ads). Maybe you clicked an advert and the URL that you opened would 1. Let facebook know that someone clicked the ad and 2. redirect you to the page so you don't know that it recorded information about you clicking that ad.

I just researched online that facebook connect is a service that allows websites to access your facebook identity - maybe the website was trying to display something like one of those comment sections at the bottom of pages that lets you post as your facebook account, and didn't expect a time out (which sounds unlikely to me, surely something would display on the website?)

Another possibility is that the page is built as a facebook app (like when facebook asks if it's ok to provide access to your basic information and allow permission to XYZ) and is perhaps trying to check the status of your facebook login and the website is clumsily built (as you say) in a way that doesn't expect the user to have blocked facebook via hosts.

Comment: I do wonder why fb would engineer their feature to effectively break the user experience of someone's potential user only because the fb servers cannot be reached. It doesn't compute for me .